# Moderator deleted two useful SO answers, leaving my own outdated answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I clicked on an upvote message and noticed that [an old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22290557/464581) had become “stale”, invalidated by the general progress of things.

That is, since early November 2015 Microsoft is again providing the Visual C++ build tools (and SDK) without Visual Studio.

Ordinary I would just have updated the answer and moved on, but I also noticed that in the three and half months that my selected-as-solution answer has provided incorrect information, two answers that provided the new and crucial information, posted to provide this information, the currently correct answer, and for nothing else, had been **deleted by a moderator**.

This deletion has suppressed useful technical information, and it should be reconsidered and used as an example in the future.

Comment: Nothing was "suppressed", the link-only answer was converted to a comment, the unnecessary duplicates removed.

Comment: @HansPassant: You're wrong. After the moderator actions the information did not appear in answers

Comment: I have edited the closing of your question, because I think that you've pointed out something worth looking at, but you go too far in implying that this is a pervasive problem requiring retraining. I think this Meta discussion will be far more constructive without that implication. If you have evidence to show that this happens a lot, then by all means present it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: It is not true that I have implied it is a pervasive problem. And you edited a bit more than you say you edited. I don't find I believe you're honest, i.e., I don't think at all that this was helpful.

Comment: Funny, we're usually lambasted for *not* deleting link-only answers. This was a clear "I agree" non-answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34735570/19679 that racked up four flags and was rightfully deleted. This: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31079990/19679 looks pretty spammy and was flagged as such. That leaves this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33558464/19679 that was converted to this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290501/can-i-download-the-visual-c-command-line-compiler-without-visual-studio/22290557#comment57221736_22290501 on the question.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf *" It is not true that I have implied it is a pervasive problem"* Great, then there's no need for retraining.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for returning my frankness with suspicion. Best of luck.

Comment: *And you edited a bit more than you say you edited.* - What, you mean the grammar corrections & noise? That's pretty typical to do in an edit. That doesn't make it dishonest.

Comment: @BradLarson: You say that the current effective guidelines make each individual action correct, with the result that the correct information is no longer in the answers. Since you use the term "lambast" I think you did *not* intend to make the case the guidelines need some revision. Yet, that is the effective argument that you, perhaps unwittingly, present. Anyway, it's not the moderators job to suppress information. When that would be the end result, then <teaspoon> **moderator should recognize the problem**, and do something about it, above what the simple guidelines require</teaspoon>.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm sorry.... a spam answer getting removed, a "I had this issue too" answer getting removed.... This isn't an issue AT ALL. The last answer, which contained relevant information.... was converted, so no data was suppressed. I don't see the need for this question. Unless there is something different than what Brad is saying IN the answers? Because if that is really what those three answers are.... there is no issue with what happened here.

Comment: Just because the information is useful doesn't mean it can be presented in a poorly manner, the answers were flagged accordingly and correct action was taken. Plus the information is now in your answer, and you've given credit where credit is due. So what's the problem now?

Comment: @Patrice: The information was no longer in the answers.  You say that is not "an issue AT ALL". That means you have no idea what a site like SO is about.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf But if it's a link only, it's NOT an answer... that's the whole point of the "link only answer" flag. If that information belongs in an answer, feel free to write it in a non "link only" way, it'll be kept (ps... stop attacking everyone who talks to you with "dishonest" "don't understand SO".... SO still has the be nice policy AFAIK.... calm down a bit)

Comment: @Patrice: Re "if it's a link only", maybe, but it's not true that a deleted answer was link only. Re the "calm down a bit", that goes to person to detract from issue, and is also untrue.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I feel like I eluded to that when I said "unless there is something different than what Brad is saying IN the answers".... I can't see the answers, I'm talking with what's given to me (right now, Brad's account).

Comment: @Patrice: Here: (http://i.stack.imgur.com/WaMOb.png).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf With the actual answers visible (thank you for that), we'll have to agree to disagree here.... the -9 is a link only. There's NOTHING but that in the answer. And the -1 is a "This answer also works for me, I got it working using it"..... If the link to the blog was kept in a comment... this has been properly handled. If you want the link in an answer... as I said, write your own answer and add some meat to it...

Comment: @Patrick: Even the "-9" is untrue. It's a "+9". And, it's untrue that there "nothing but [the link]". There is, quoting: "It's now supported by Microsoft", which is crucial information, plus the link to where it can be found, which is also crucial. And that's all the crucial information.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf and my name is Patrice, not Patrick. Everyone makes mistakes ;). Anyway I can see where you're coming from, but to me, "microsoft now support this" is not enough to make this a non-link only. As I said, we can pretty much just agree to disagree here.

Comment: No, there's no issue that can be disagreed on. The facts are plain, and they include that the answer-converted-to-comment, with 9 upvotes and no downvotes, at the time was *the* full  answer to the question. The only that can be disagreed on is which flock of sheep do we want to belong to.

Comment: Wow, you're so defensive you even back out of the statement that we won't get to agree.... you're really something man. Anyway, I said my piece, you said yours... no one seems to have changed states... with your last comment, I don't see this going back to the constructive side of discussions. Have a good one!

Comment: @Patrice: re "going back to the constructive side of discussion", with mostly misleading statements present, even misleading you about whether an answer was upvoted or downvoted, I fail to see any constructive discussion here. I'm posting to Meta not for the discussion: this is more of a fan-boy place, not the place for constructive discussion. It's more of a **heads-up**. Doing my duty.

Comment: A moderator has just edited my answer and **deleted the attributions**. I feel ashamed on your behalf. I rolled it back.

Comment: That  moderator has just deleted the attributions again. Moderators engaging in edit wars! What next?

Comment: Flagging for closure, OP isn't clearly open minded enough to have an objective argument about the subject. Instead he is being rude and attacks whoever doesn't share his perspective. Mentalities like this should be avoided. Best to close the post and move on.

Comment: @Alf The content I removed is *pure* noise. It has no business in an SO answer. The attributes serve no purpose as you specifically state in the question that you are now unable to link to the source material.

Comment: @meagar: Nobody believe you, but many may applaude you. I don't.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Speak for yourself.

Answer (score 14):

I agree with you that the answer which read "It's now supported by Microsoft." was useful and that's precisely why I converted it into a comment instead of flat out deleting.

Where I don't agree with you however is that it met the current community understanding of the line between an answer and a comment.

The answer which began with "I agree with the answer from: 9 down vote" [clearly](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10858979) was a user who lacked both upvote and comment anywhere privileges  looking for a way to say "thanks" like the other 9 upvoters did.

In converting the older one to a comment I hoped to allow the useful update to live on until such time as someone stepped up and wrote it into a more fully featured answer.

I didn't do that myself at the time because I don't think that's the right use of moderator time, it simply doesn't scale if moderators start doing all the things they see that can and should be done by the community.

In converting it to a comment I hoped that someone within the community would come along later and step up, writing a complete answer which included that. This could be the person who posted the answer editing it, the owner of one of the other answers or an entirely new answer.

*And that's exactly what has happened here.*

Sure, it would be nice if the 9 upvotes on the answer made their way into being 9 comment upvotes in the conversion process, to give it prominence but that's a relatively minor feature request.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. A problem I see is that for 3+ months someone coming from google, say, would look only at *my currently incorrect answer*. So assuming for the sake of discussion (I disagree, but assuming) that the conversion to comment was the right thing to do, I think additional action was clearly called for. E.g. I would have edited the selected solution answer with a comment clearly marked as such, just a moderator's *fact*. I sometimes did that when I was active mod of comp.lang.c++.moderated. Facts are the purpose of the group. Other mod editing, like your colleague's, is unsound.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Moderators cannot possibly review everything that may be linking to a specific answer before deleting it. This is one of the reasons link-only answers are discouraged. Links break, it's a fact of life.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That's not how mods work _here._ If they did there, then cool- But here they're basically janitors. Their job is to clean up stuff the community can't, or hasn't yet. The community can't delete upvoted answers, so mods have to do that. Otherwise, I can almost guarantee 3 20k users would've done it instead. Meagar was _also_ cleaning up, by removing unnecessary commentary from your answer.

Comment: @meagar: You're adding noise, for the umpteenth time. Which is **not constructive**. No review was necessary. It was not a link only answer. A link was implied in the question about where to get it (can't do that without linking). The thing about "links break" is not a valid criticism of providing the answer. If your logic was followed the question could not be answered.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yes, a link *was* implied by the question, and you'll also note that I closed the question almost an hour ago, as it's completely off-topic by today's standards. Questions asking for links to off-site resources are as off-topic as answers which provide no meaningful content except for off-site links. You are right: The question can not be answered here. "Where can I download X" is off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Regarding @meagar's contention that the question is off-topic. The question is **Can I download the Visual C++ Command Line Compiler without Visual Studio?**. Few if any ordinary SO users would agree that it's off topic. The conclusion is arrived at by misrepresenting the question with a generalization. That's not constructive.